# Pixelated shadows and obvious seams when rendering

Tags: rendering, shadows

whatever I do, I keep getting these annoying shading lines when I render. my GPU is an rtx2070 super and I'm using OptiX render settings.

I was editing an old project and had to import the fbx to a new scene because the settings in the old scene were causing me to have half-hour predicted render times for something with 4000 tris. also, no shadows were showing up no matter what I did. presumably, I messed with some settings by accident a while back and I couldn't figure out what.

here's the viewport render

[image: Rendering in viewport with bad shading]

and the actual F12 render

[image: f12 Render]

Please help :(

**EDIT**

I've attached a link to a google drive folder with the file in it. I'm remotely accessing my pc from my phone atm so if there's a way to upload files on this site that's why I couldn't find it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LVEc-kneE1CcPOu8bCxRSYxId8eeWC9A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, can you please share more info? Did you try to play with faces orientation? What about shading smooth and changing to smooth value? What value is there? This really seems like shading problem. Can you share your file?

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: i'll upload the file now! didn't think about that

Comment: uploaded the file now, sorry it took so long